# Hausdorff dimension of the graph of a BV function

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $u: \Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^M$ be a $BV$ function.

> Is the Hausdorff dimension of the graph of $u$ equal to $N$? How can we prove it?

---

**Update.**

1. In an [answer to this post](http://tps://mathoverflow.net/a/327310/122620), it has been showed that there exist a representative $\tilde u$ of $u$ such that its graph has Hausdorff dimension equal to $N$.
2. In a subsequent post [If the Hausforff dimension of the graph of a function $u$ is $N$ and $\tilde u = u$ a.e. then $\dim_H \mathrm{graph} \, \tilde u = N$ too](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327331/if-the-hausforff-dimension-of-the-graph-of-a-function-u-is-n-and-tilde-u) it has been showed that a function can be zero a.e. and still its graph may have dimension strictly greater than $1$. So probably this question is better formulated in terms of *essential graph* of $u$, which possibly is equivalent to asking for the property to hold for one representative of $u$ (see Question 2 in [Hausdorff dimension of the graph of a BV function (in 1 dimensional setting)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327698/hausdorff-dimension-of-the-graph-of-a-bv-function-in-1-dimensional-setting))
3. In the post [Hausdorff dimension of the graph of a BV function (in 1 dimensional setting)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327698/hausdorff-dimension-of-the-graph-of-a-bv-function-in-1-dimensional-setting), I've asked about a simpler proof of the result in the one-dimensional setting.

Comment: I suppose you meant $N$, not $1$?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partial answer here.

Let us recall the following Lusin type result (see e.g. Theorem 5.34 in *Functions of bounded variation* by L. Ambrosio, N. Fusco and D. Pallara):

> **Theorem 1.** There exists a constant $\kappa>0$ such that for every $u\in BV(\mathbb R^N)$ and $\lambda>0$ there exists a Lipschitz function $v_\lambda \in \mathrm{Lip}(\mathbb R^N)$ such that
>   $$
> |x\in \mathbb R^N : u(x)\ne v_\lambda(x)| \le \frac{\kappa}{\lambda} |Du|(\mathbb R^N).
> $$

Let us denote $D_\lambda := \{x\in \mathbb R^N : u(x) = v_\lambda(x)\}$
and $D := \bigcup_{\lambda \in \mathbb N} D_\lambda$. It is evident that the complement $D^c = \mathbb R^n \setminus D$ is Lebesgue negligible.

Let us show that the Hausdorff dimension of the graph $\Gamma_D:=\{(x,u(x)) : x\in D\}$ is $N$. Clearly it is sufficient to show that the Hausdorff dimension of the graph $\Gamma_{D_\lambda}:=\{(x,u(x)) : x\in D_\lambda\}$ is $N$ for each $\lambda\in \mathbb N$. And this is true because $u\colon D_\lambda \to \mathbb R$ coincides with Lipschitz function $v_\lambda \colon D_\lambda \to \mathbb R$. Thus we have proved the following claim:

> **Proposition 1.** If $u$ is a $BV$ function then there exists $\tilde u \in BV$ such that $\tilde u = u$ a.e. and the Hausdorff dimension of the graph of $\tilde u$ is $N$.

What remains not clear to me at the moment is whether the claim is true for every representative of $u$. But note that the answer to this question does not depend on $BV$ regularity of $u$, and can essentially be formulated as follows:

*Question.* Suppose that $u\colon [0,1]\to [0,1]$ is a measurable function such that $u=0$ a.e. Is it true that the Hausdorff dimension of the graph of $u$ is at most $1$?

Comment: Thank you. I've asked that last question as a separate post (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327331/if-the-hausforff-dimension-of-the-graph-of-a-function-u-is-n-and-tilde-u). Why do you pose it only in $1$ dimension? That is, how can you deduce the $N$-dimensional statement from that?

Comment: Also, why is it sufficient to show that the Hausdorff dimension of the graph $\Gamma_{D_\lambda}:=\{(x,u(x)) : x\in D_\lambda\}$ is $N$ for each $\lambda\in \mathbb N$? That is, why can we "pass to the limit" in that expression?

Comment: @Riku because $\Gamma_{D} = \bigcup_{\lambda \in \mathbb N} \Gamma_{D_\lambda}$, and [Hausdorff dimension is stable under taking countable unions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772140/countable-stability-of-hausdorff-dimension). And thank you for reposting a more general version of my question in a separate thread. I do not claim that the $N-$dimensional statement can be deduced from the one-dimesional. But I think that the simpler version is easier to address, and maybe its solution could be adopted for the general case.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a simpler proof (that does not rely on Theorem 1) in the case $N=M=1$ that the graph of a BV function has Hausdorff dimension equal to 1?

Comment: I've asked the question in my last comment in a different post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327698/hausdorff-dimension-of-the-graph-of-a-bv-function-in-1-dimensional-setting