# Hausdorff dimension of the graph of a BV function (in 1 dimensional setting)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $u: \Omega\subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function of bounded variation.

**Question 1.**

How can we prove that the Hausdorff dimension of the [essential graph](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327698/hausdorff-dimension-of-the-graph-of-a-bv-function-in-1-dimensional-setting?noredirect=1#comment818424_327698) of $u$ equal to $1$?

**Question 2.**

Is Question 1 equivalent to asking the following?

*How can we prove that there exists a representative $\tilde u$ of $u$ such that the Hausdorff dimension of $\tilde u$ is equal to 1.*

---

**Note.**
I've asked a more general question [Hausdorff dimension of the graph of a BV function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327267/hausdorff-dimension-of-the-graph-of-a-bv-function/327310?noredirect=1#comment817269_327310), which has received a very nice (partial) answer, however, I'd like to see a simpler proof in the 1-dimensional case.

Comment: You can cover the graph by roughly 1/r balls of radius r.

Comment: @Riku Probably it makes sense to specify what you mean by graph, because a function can be zero a.e. and still its graph may have dimension strictly greater than 1, see my answer here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327331

Comment: @AnthonyQuas What do you mean?

Comment: @Skeeve You're right. What would the appropriate definition of graph be?

Comment: @Riku there is a notion of [essential range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_range). Maybe it would be appropriate to define similarly *essential graph*, i.e. to say that *essential graph* of $u$ is the essential range of the function $x\mapsto(x,u(x))$.

Comment: @Skeeve Thank you. Yes, that seems to be an appropriate notion.

Comment: @Skeeve Is this rephrasing of the question equivalent to asking if there is a representative of $u$ such that its graph has dimension 1?

Comment: I think so. Maybe you also want to update your previous question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327267/hausdorff-dimension-of-the-graph-of-a-bv-function/327310?noredirect=1#comment817269_327310

Comment: @Skeeve I've edited this post adding a question 2. If the answer to question 2 is yes, I should indeed update the previous question as well.

Comment: I don't understand this business about representatives at all. Just as for continuous functions, it seems highly artificial to modify the function on a null set (and possibly destroy its defining property). More precisely, a BV function has at most countably many discontinuities, and obviously the values at those won't matter here, so why not just go with the function itself rather than consider other (possibly not BV) functions that agree with it a.e.?

Comment: @ChristianRemling My current understanding of the situation is unclear as well. It would be very nice if you could weight in on it.  I've written up the motivation of this question and progress in the update to the question in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327267/hausdorff-dimension-of-the-graph-of-a-bv-function

Comment: @Skeeve I've updated the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327267/hausdorff-dimension-of-the-graph-of-a-bv-function to reflect the progress and mark what is still a bit unclear to me. By the way, thank you for your help on all these problems.

Comment: @ChristianRemling everything depends on which definition of a BV function is considered. The standard one is an integrable function whose weak derivative is a measure. Clearly weak derivatives are not sensitive to modifications of the function on negligible sets. But as you can see e.g. from from my answer here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327331 the Hausdorff dimension of the graph is sensitive to modifications of the function on the negligible sets.

Comment: @Skeeve: Yes, that works as a characterization, but wouldn't it be much more natural here to go with the more elementary condition (used in all books I have ever come across as the definition) of having finite total variation?

Comment: @Skeeve: And in fact, I would state the theorem you refer to as "a distribution has its derivative equal to a finite measure if and only if it's induced by a BV function" (note that the *functions* come first, the non-uniqueness only arises when we let them induce distributions), though that might be getting too pedantic now.

Comment: @Riku: For what it's worth, I would state your question as "does the graph of a BV function have Hd dim 1." This seems perfectly clear and (to me) the natural version of your question. But I'm not saying it's the only possible opinion.

Comment: @ChristianRemling In an [earlier related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327267) a multi-dimensional setting was considered, where [the distributional definition of BV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#BV_functions_of_several_variables) is natural. For comparison of the two definitions see e.g. the book *Functions of bounded variation* by Ambrosio, Fusco and Pallara (p. 134). So (in my opinion) it makes sense to explicitly state which definition is considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume $\Omega$ is an interval $[a,b]$, say. I assume this was intended as part of your question.

Let $\text{Var}f=M$. Let $r>0$. The function has at most countably many discontinuities, which are necessarily of jump type. The magnitude of the discontinuities sums to at most $M$. In particular, there are at most $M/r$ points at which the function jumps by $r$ or more. Let these be $z_1,\ldots, z_k$. Let $z_0=a$ and $z_1=b$. Then on each interval $(z_i,z_{i+1})$, there exist $z_i:=x^i_0<x^i_1<\ldots<x^i_{n_i}:=z_{i+1}$ such that $r<\text{Var}_{[x^i_j,x^i_{j+1}]}(f)<2r$ for each $i,j$, except that no lower bound is imposed for $j=n_i-1$ (that is the variation is split into chunks of size roughly $r$). Now the part of the graph lying over $[x_j^i,x_{j+1}^i]$ can be covered by approximately $\lceil (x^i_{j+1}-x^i_j)/r\rceil$ balls of radius $r$, so that approximately $N_i=(z_{i+1}-z_i)/r+n_i+1$ balls are needed to cover the section of the graph lying over $[z_i,z_{i+1}]$. Notice that $n_i\le \text{Var}_{(z_i,z_{i+1})}f/r+1$, so that summing the $N_i$'s we obtain a cover with approximate $(b-a)/r+\text{Var}_{[a,b]}f/r+k$ balls of size $r$. Since $k\le M/r$, we see the number of balls is bounded by approximately $(b-a)/r+2M/r$. Hence the Hausdorff dimension is at most 1.

Comment: Thank you. 1) How do you prove that the function has at most countably many discontinuities, which are necessarily of jump type? 2) Why are there at most M/r points at which the function jumps by r or more? 3) You conclude that $\dim graph(f) \le 1$. How do you show that it is also $\ge 1$?

Comment: The facts you’re asking for are standard. For 3, the image under projection onto the first coordinated has Hausdorff dimension 1, and projections don’t increase dimension (you can just project the covering to get a new covering)

Comment: I guess they are standard, but I've never seen the proofs. For (1), it should follow by considering that a BV function is sum of a decreasing and an increasing function. But what about (2)?

Comment: Because if the were more than M/r points with jump r, then the total variation would be more than M/r. * r