# Box counting dimension of the graph of a BV function

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $u: \Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^M$ be a $BV$ function.

> Is the box counting dimension of the graph of $u$ equal to $N$? How can we prove it?

---

The analogous question for the Hausdorff dimension was asked in [Hausdorff dimension of the graph of a BV function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327267/hausdorff-dimension-of-the-graph-of-a-bv-function) (where related issues are also mentioned).